# How can I get css max-height to work correctly?

Tags: css

and help! :-)

Im not really a coder, but trying to set up a web page that has an iframe with an embedded canvas that is responsive. I'd like the animation to scale up to a certain point, but afterwards remain fixed.  I seem to have achieved that, but am having problems with the iframe which keeps on getting bigger.  The code im using is a padding trick for getting iframes to scale proportionally to it's content. But max-height doesn't seem to have any affect on it. The test page is here:

https://iamsteve.co.uk/test1/

The black is the iframe background, the blue is the wrapper background, which is what seems to be causing me such a headache!  How can i get the blue to stop expanding?

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 44.5%;">
    
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: 0;" src="https://iamsteve.co.uk/houseofholmes/test.html" gesture="media"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>

<style>
    .wrapper {
        background-color: blue;
        max-height: 400px;
    }
    iframe {
        max-height: 400px;
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!  many thanks. Steve

Comment: you mean you want to remove the blue area? let me know

Comment: hi yes, remove the blue area - i can't change the percentage of the padding, as that ensure the ratio for the content stays the same. It's some css trick i found online and seems to be used for video content, 4:3 or 16:9, but im using it for my animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to look on your code. try this if I understand you right.Seems like adjusting your padding-top which you use to get the right area you want on iframe just needed to be less %. You also can add a pretend div on top of the iframe and adjust height and width of it.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-top:30%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 30%;">
```

Comment: hey i tried this and it seems to work. not sure how it will be on very large screens. very strange because I didn't think I could change the percentage figure without messing things up. it's a trick i found online normally for video content, and the percentage is calculated by dividing the height by width . I will try this out a bit more on bigger screens and see if it still works but have a feeling on larger monitors the blue space will come back. appreciate your help.

Comment: just had a look on my ipad in portrait mode, and no blue !  :-)) thanks crystal. really appreciate it.

Comment: hey Crystal - just an update for you. Changing the percentage does work, , but unfortunately it also changes the final width of the animation, not by much, and I can probably get away with it. But ideally what would work better is some kind of css / code that restricts the height of the wrapper once its the same height of the animation. Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: if you give it a height padding or margins and control it using media query that might work. but controlling an iframe is not possible(unless you own this iframe page). you can put some pretend div with a height or width on top on an iframe and call it on media query to kind a control it.. let me know aht you've tried then we can look again

Comment: HI again Crystal. I managed to sort it out in the end - bit of a fluke really, but as its being built in elementor, i managed to fix the width of the container, and it seems to have stopped the issue of the iframe expanding. thanks for your time, you've been really helpful. :-)) best wishes. Steve

Comment: I'm glad to help. No worries please accept the answer so it will show that your issue is already resolved. Have a happy coding..

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: @SteveDM click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks